# Force results to be displayed in a way often seen in traditional math

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation, argument-patterns

I want to get my output in the form that I would write by hand. I have tried with `TraditionalForm`, but it did not work.

I've looked at several answers in this SE group, but I can't find any that help me.

[image]

```
a^(2/3) - a^(1/3) b^(1/3) + b^(2/3)
```

> ```
> Power[a^2, (3)^-1] - Power[ab, (3)^-1] + Power[b^2, (3)^-1]
> ```

```
a^(3/4) - Sqrt[a] b^(1/4) + a^(1/4) Sqrt[b] - b^(3/4)
```

> ```
> Power[a^3, (4)^-1] - Power[a^2 b, (4)^-1] + Power[ab^2, (4)^-1] - 
>   Power[b^3, (4)^-1]
> ```

```
a^(4/5) - a^(3/5) b^(1/5) + a^(2/5) b^(2/5) - a^(1/5) b^(3/5) + b^(4/5)
```

> ```
> Power[a^4, (5)^-1] - Power[a^3 b, (5)^-1] + Power[a^2 b^2, (5)^-1] -  
>    Power[ab^3, (5)^-1] + Power[b^4, (5)^-1]
> ```

Comment: Use `TraditionalForm`; however, do not include the wrapper in the definitions. For example, `(expr1 = a^(2/3) - a^(1/3) b^(1/3) + b^(2/3)) // TraditionalForm`

Comment: I recommend this question be reopened because the is no simple mistake and a solution is certainly not easy to find in the docs. The question as originally posted was just a little unclear. I hope my editing has fixed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name your expressions and end them with a semicolon ( ; ), so that naming assignment doesn't display. Then display the named expression with `TraditionalForm`. Like so;

```
expr = a^(4/5) - a^(3/5) b^(1/5) + a^(2/5) b^(2/5) - a^(1/5) b^(3/5) + b^(4/5);
expr // TraditionalForm
```

[image: expr]

#### Update

Taking Michael E2's comment as pointing out that my 1st solution isn't good enough, I offer this:

```
xf1[u_^(p_Rational)] := Surd[u^Numerator[p], Denominator[p]]
xf2[Times[u_., Surd[a_^i_., n_], Surd[b_^j_., n_]]] := u Surd[Times[a^i, b^j], n]
xexpr = Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {xf1, xf2}]
```

[image: expr]

Note that

```
Simplify[expr == xexpr, a > 0 && b > 0]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I think `Simplify[expr, a > 0 && b > 0] // TraditionalForm` gets closer to the OPs goal.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you, it works perfectly, and thank you to others for answering